# padding MNIST dataset with tf.pad()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

How to pad MNIST dataset images of size `(?,28,28,1)` with `tf.pad()` and make it `(?,32,32,1)` in tensorflow?

Comment: which part of the tf documentation is not clear to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how do you plan to pad it. On example is like this:

```
# Assuming input is a tensor with shape (?, 28, 28, 1)
output = tf.pad(input, [[0, 0], [2,2], [2,2], [0,0]])
# print(tf.shape(output)) should be (?, 32, 32, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Max, this is exactly what I was also looking for.